# Cannot get setOnActionExpandListener to work since updating to sdk 26

Tags: android, menu

I keep getting this error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()` when this code is called: `searchView.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() { ..`

(cannot really post more than this as it is a client's app)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 searchView.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener(){
```

use

```
 (MenuItemCompat)searchView.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){
```

note: searchView should be an instance of MenuItemCompat, instead of MenuItem

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer... the searchView is not a child of MenuItemCompat and as such I cannot cast it. Also if I use MenuItemCompat, its set listener shows up as deprecated and I get the exact same exception